# Offset/shift image pixels on a given range in python

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, transformation, offset

I'd like to offset an image's pixels from a given starting value till the max value on the x axis with a given offset value.
I'm quite new to python, thats why i could only manage to shift the entire image.
How can i manage this?

Here is my goal in the end:

[1. A map with folding grid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogasg.jpg)[2. A map with shifted pages on the foldings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1HN8g.jpg)

Comment: are these 8 different images or just one

Comment: its only one image, what i what to "shrink" with the partial offsets.

Comment: For example: There is an image what is 800x600px, first i want to offset with -20px from 600px till  max(800px) on x axis. Than i want to do this for loop from 400 till max an 200 till max, and than i want to write out the image.